# How can I print a document with textboxes showing? (vB)

Tags: vb.net, printing, textbox

So I have been trying to print a document where the textboxes are shown on top of a picturebox, however it just doesn't seem to work.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class Form1
Dim WithEvents mPrintDocument As New PrintDocument
Dim mPrintBitMap As Bitmap
```

---

```
Private Sub m_PrintDocument_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles mPrintDocument.PrintPage
    ' Draw the image centered.
    Dim lWidth As Integer = e.MarginBounds.X + (e.MarginBounds.Width / 0.95 - mPrintBitMap.Width) \ 1
    Dim lHeight As Integer = e.MarginBounds.Y + (e.MarginBounds.Height / 0.9 - mPrintBitMap.Height) \ 2
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(mPrintBitMap, lWidth, lHeight)

    ' There's only one page.
    e.HasMorePages = False
End Sub


    Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    picFij.SendToBack()
    lblDN.BringToFront()

    mPrintBitMap = New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Width)
    Dim lRect As System.Drawing.Rectangle
    lRect.Width = Me.Width
    lRect.Height = Me.Width
    Me.DrawToBitmap(mPrintBitMap, lRect)



    mPrintDocument = New PrintDocument
    printPreviewDialog1.Document = mPrintDocument
    PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

I attempted a BringToFront() and SendToBack() but that didn't work.

This is what I want to print:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/358502382910570497/546555282940100648/unknown.png

And this is print preview
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/358502382910570497/546555621806178324/unknown.png

Any ideas?

Comment: It may be worth your while to look into [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/printing/printform-component).

Comment: Is that a TextBox or a RichTextBox? If the latter, it won't print its content using the `DrawToBitmap` method (background color included). It's a well-known limitation of the RTB. You'll have to print its text *manually*. Or use a standard TextBox, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Make the PictureBox the Parent of your TextBox, then it should show up when you call DrawToBitmap().  For example, to keep TextBox1 in the same location, convert it screen coords, then back to client coords with respect to the PictureBox:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim pt As Point = TextBox1.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))
    TextBox1.Parent = PictureBox1
    TextBox1.Location = PictureBox1.PointToClient(pt)
End Sub
```